# How to update another table if they are related?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables tbLicence and tbCompanyAgent as shown in the screenshot

[image]

there are some common columns values present in tbCompanyAgent as that of in tbLicence like LicenseNumber, LicenseIssueDate and LicenseExpirationDate. After some complex sql querires and business requirement, the columns StateIssuedLicenseNumber, StateIssuedLicenseIssueDate and StatedIssuedLicenseExpirationDate and the columns LicenceNumber, DateIssued and ExpirationDate in tbLicence are merged to a single column LicenseNumber, LicenseIssueDate and LicenseExpirationDate in tbCompanyAgent.

Also values in StateIssuedLicenseNumber, StateIssuedLicenseIssueDate and StatedIssuedLicenseExpirationDate are same for same group of records identified by Group Id Column LicenceType.

Actually there is one resident entry for all the licences which are stored in
StateIssuedLicenseNumber, StateIssuedLicenseIssueDate and StatedIssuedLicenseExpirationDate columns and are identified by Resident column with 1 value.

Non Resident Licences are stored in LicenceNumber, DateIssued and ExpirationDate  with 0 value.

My Question is if user try to make some updation in tbLicence that should be reflected on tbCompanyAgent. How will I write query. Please help!!!

Comment: you can use update with join.

Comment: Can u plz provide query...

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger for that.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

It should be ON UPDATE trigger. Rows which were updated will be in pseudo-table *inserted*.

Here you can see a good example

> [SQL Triggers - how do I get the updated value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796281/sql-triggers-how-do-i-get-the-updated-value)

Comment: It is not possible for me to use triggers because I have to insert licences in loop and for updating them i have to first delete all the licences together on the basis of group id column LicenceType and then reinsert them in loop. I have to do like this because of complex business requirement. Please provide alternate queries...

Comment: Then, I'd say, you need AFTER INSERT trigger. When it runs, you need to find appropriate row from another column (by joining table 'inserted' to tbCompanyAgent on some unique attribute). And if you find row - just update it with new values).